# How to send data to view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, razor

I have tables, to which I can send data, everything is set up, now I only need to understand, how to send data to view. When I want to get data using `Model` word, I'm getting error: *`NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`*.

**index.cshtml**

```
@model FaqVM
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}

@Model.MainCategoryTitle // Error
```

**Faq.cs**

```
public class Faq : CanBeLocalized, IHaveIntegerId, ICanProvideCreatedTime, IHaveConcurrencyToken
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Localize] public string MainCategoryTitle { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public string ConcurrencyToken { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Disabled { get; set; }
    public int SOrder { get; set; } = 0;
    public DateTime? Updated { get; set; }
    public ICollection<FaqSubcategory> FaqSubcategories { get; set; } = new HashSet<FaqSubcategory>();
}
```

**FaqVM.cs**

```
public class FaqVM
{
    public string MainCategoryTitle { get; set; }
    public List<FaqSubcategory> FaqSubcategories { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

```
   public class CmsController : Controller
    {
        protected ILocale _locale;
        protected ICacheManager _cacheManager;
        protected RegionProvider _regionProvider;
        protected IViewRenderService _viewRenderService;
        private IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

        //...
    }

    public class FaqController : CmsController
    {
        private readonly Faq _faq;

        public FaqController(
            RegionProvider regionProvider, 
            ILocaleAccessor localeAccessor, 
            ILiteralProvider literalProvider,
            CartRepo cartRepo,
            IServiceProvider serviceProvider,
            Faq faq) : base(serviceProvider)
        {
            _faq = faq;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var vm = new FaqVM
            {
                MainCategoryTitle = _faq.MainCategoryTitle,
                FaqSubcategories = _faq.FaqSubcategories.ToList()
            };

            return View(vm);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: So, **FaqVM.cs** is your controller? If you are trying to build a MVC project (not Razor-Pages) project then your controller is not properly set!

Comment: @ShahriarRahmanZahin No, FaqVM is ViewModel, added code of controller

Comment: What does **CmsController** contain? In addition you have to pass the model from controller like this: "return View(model);". Otherwise you will not be able to find the model in your view

Comment: Thanks, I updated the code. `CmsController` derives from `Controller` class and contain some general functionality for many classes. Now, when I send model, I getting error: Unable to resolve service for type 'Bs.WebApp.Models.Faq' while attempting to activate 'Bs.WebApp.Controllers.FaqController'.

Comment: So, now that you are sending **vm** as the model please update your view for receiving **vm** instead of **FaqVM**

Comment: I think you need to create a new question. This is no longer related to your original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your Index() method in your FaqController you need to create your ViewModel as fx

```
var vm = new FaqVM(){
     MainCategoryTitle = "test",
     FaqSubcategories = new List<FaqSubcategory>(){ new FaqSubcategory() }
}
```

and then you need to pass the ViewModel to the return part of your Index method:

```
return View(vm);
```

Typically you would create your vm from some data from a database or some user input.